# Querying objects inside objects in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, querying

I would like to be querying my database. Unfortunately I cannot access to the objects that are inside the "_id" : "ObjectId". I have a large amount of objects "1", "2"... "n".

How would you query all objects with "RFC": "AAA020211GV8" for example?

I do not understand the structure and why I just have a very big object with 10,000 objects inside.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post image post the documents. Images are difficult to work with. Just copy/past

Comment: Ok, thanks for the recommendation